# window.open popup without toolbar and UI parts

Tags: javascript, html, dom, window.open

I am trying to make a popup that is a new browser window, so I can change tabs and still have this popup.
I want it to be with a minimal UI (toolbars, menubars, addressbar, etc).
I tried something like that:

```
window.open('test.html', 'popup', 'left=100,top=100,width=320,height=320,popup=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,location=0')
```

But it still show the UI. Is there any way to create new window without the UI?

Comment: In the very old days, you could control many aspects of the new window, but for security reasons, most browsers won't allow you to hide the address bar. For other settings try setting the value to "no" instead of "0".

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and mine with Opera and it didn't change anything. But on Safari and Chrome I managed to get a minimal UI. Here's what I used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to open a new window with some specifications.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no,status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=yes, width=600, height=600");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```